# Would you use autolayout or calculate the height of each UITableViewCell if you were building the Facebook iOS app?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm building an app that has very complex and dynamic UITableViewCells (similar to facebook's app).  Each cell is very complicated and has dynamic heights (which are always changing as things happen)

Would it be better to use the autolayout method (`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`) or calculate the height of each cell manually using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

For extremely complicated cells, which route should I go?

Comment: [Better how?](http://importblogkit.com/2016/03/how-to-ask-a-good-stack-overflow-question/)  By what criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Far as, I suggest and using since Xcode 6.4 that `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works much better than calculating the height manually.

One thing, I notice that if you have content in `UITableViewCell` that changing constantly then you don't go for calculating the height manually because every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will call and height will be calculated accordingly.

So, in that case, you will get a lag while scrolling up / down. That's the reason `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is best.

I have developed an app which has almost same UI as of Facebook and in that I have used `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and it works smoothly.

Here is an app, which you can look at it. [Dancinglog](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/dancinglog-for-all-dancers/id1062547040?mt=8)

> Update

If you can say then I can show that particular code in that I have managed 5 different types of `UITableViewCell` having different views and contents.